# Foreach loop inside while loop - it never ends

Tags: php

So, I have one curl API call which works fine when I do foreach outside the while loop. Once I move the foreach inside (because I need the values inside) it becomes an infinity loop.

This is the setup

```
$query = "SELECT id, vote FROM `administrators` WHERE type = 'approved'";
$result = $DB->query($query);

$offset = 0;
$length = 5000;
    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
                    
do {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.gov/data?api_key=xxxxxxxxxx&start=1960&sort[0][direction]=desc&offset=$offset&length=$length");
    
  $jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
  $response = json_decode($jsonData);
                
  foreach($response->response->data as $finalData){
      $allData[] = $finalData; 
  }
    
  $offset += count($response->response->data);
    
} while ( count($response->response->data) > 0 );
    
curl_close($ch); 

while($row = $DB->fetch_object($result)) {

   foreach ( $allData as $key => $finalData1 ) {
         
        // rest of the code
   }
}
```

Once I run the page it goes infinity or until my browser crash. If I move `foreach ( $allData as $key => $finalData1 ) { }` outside the `while(){}` there is no such problem.

Any ideas on what can be the problem here?

UPDATE: `// rest of the code`

```
$dataValue = str_replace(array("--","(s)","NA"),"NULL",$finalData1->value);
if($frequency == "dayly") {
    if($dataValue) {
        $query = "UPDATE table SET $data_field = $dataValue WHERE year = $finalData1->period AND id = $row->id LIMIT 1";
    }
}

if(isset($query))
$DB->query($query);
unset($query);
```

Comment: `$row = $DB->fetch_object($result)` Here, you are executing query every time. It is not equivalent to fetching rows one by one.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `break;` after the `foreach` to stop it after the first loop.  See how long that takes.

Comment: You'll want some logging to find out what's going on. You don't have `$result` defined here, nor do you show what the query is, so right now the only thing the two loops have in common is the `$allData`. Know that every time you go through the database results, you go through the whole $allData again, which may or may not be what you need. Whatever is in the comment may also be affecting your code, depending on the variable names.

Comment: This is the case I believe and this is what I don't want. `You don't have $result defined here, nor do you show what the query is, so right now the only thing the two loops have in common is the $allData. Know that every time you go through the database results, you go through the whole $allData again`

Comment: You're not using `$row` at all, so you don't need that while loop at all.

Comment: Sorry, it is used in the update query. I've copied the one without because I was tested without `while` to see if it will go to infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues could be that where

```php
// rest of the code
```

is, you have duplicate variable names, thus overriding current positions in arrays and loops.

However, you should change your approach to something like

```php
$rows = Array();
while($row = $DB->fetch_object($result)) $rows[] = $row;

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  foreach ($allData as $key => $finalData1) {
    // rest of the code
  }
}
```

That way you can read resultset from database faster and free it before you continue.

Comment: In `// rest of code` have just one update query. I have checked all variables for duplicates also. Let me try what you suggest.

Comment: Still same with this approach.

Comment: How can you be sure it's infinite loop?

Comment: because I know how many rows I have in the database + how many rows are coming from the curl request. When I stop the page from loading and search for some value it's there multiple times - repeatedly.

Comment: So which one is going infinite, first or second, in your opinion?

Comment: `foreach ($allData as $key => $finalData1)` this one goes infinite when it is in the while, so, I guess it is because the while.

Comment: So if you do just this:
```for ($key=0; $key < count($allData); $key++) {
  $finalData1 = $allData[$key];
  var_dump($key, $finalData1);
}```
It loops indefinitely?

Comment: Yes, goes indefinitely inside the while loop.

Comment: And if you add `var_dump($row)` before the `for ()`, do you get output only on the first row?

Comment: Well in the current context it makes no sense, the problem is most definitely inside the second loop, and without seeing it's code, I don't think you can have further help.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the rest of the code. It's really just two if blocks and one update.

Comment: When you tested with `for ($key=0; ....` did you remove your code?

Comment: Currently, it is as your snippet above and the `for ($key=0; ....` is inside the second foreach

Comment: Yes, but with or without your updates? I was wondering if it is ONLY my snippet does it still loop?

Comment: Nope, not only yours. If I put back my code and add `for ($key=0;...)` still does it.

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($key)` before your code (if you're using `for` that I wrote) and see if key gets stuck at 0, or what happens?

Comment: Sorry, got confused. My code = is the one from the question? And to add `var_dump($key)` and the `for ($key=0; ...` before while?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245853/discussion-between-s-i-and-dkasipovic).

Comment: It turns out that the loop is not infinite just takes a long time when there are more IDs that can go through thousands of data from the API. Example: 300 ids * 9000 elements.